# Printing first 3 decimal places without rounding

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

Okay, I know there is a question quite similar already, but it didn't quite answer my question. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong though.

I have written a program that gets a temperature in Fahrenheit from the user and converts it to Celcius. It looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenheitToCelcius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double fahrenheit;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: ");

        fahrenheit = sc.nextDouble();  
        double celcius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

        String num = String.format("%.3f", celcius);

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(fahrenheit + "F" + " is " + num + "C");
    } 
}
```

When it prints the answer out, I want only the first 3 decimal places printed, but not rounded. For example, if the input is `100F`, I want `37.777C` printed, **not** `37.778C`.

I have tried using `DecimalFormat` and `String.format` (like above), but both methods print out `37.778C`. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your answers, and I apologise if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for that edit, John.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat`, just set the [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
String num = df.format(celcius);
```

Answer (score 5):

Multiply celsius by 1000 to move the decimal over 3 spots

```
celsius = celsius * 1000;
```

Now floor the number and divide by 1000

```
celsius = Math.floor(celsius) / 1000;
```

It will remove the need for the String.format() method.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to using Math.floor but probably easier to just cast to int:

Want 2 decimal places? Try this:

`System.out.println( (int) (your_double * 100) / 100.0 );`

Want 3 decimal places? Try this:

`System.out.println( (int) (your_double * 1000) / 1000.0 );`

Want 4 decimal places? Try this:

`System.out.println( (int) (your_double * 10000) / 10000.0 );`

See the pattern? Multiple your double by 10 to the power of the number of decimals you want. After cast, divide by same with decimal zero appended.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply round until 4 decimal places then trim the last character.

```
String num = String.format("%.4f", celcius);

num = num.substring(0, num.length() - 1);
```