# Only 2 digit after decimal point without last 2 digit rounding off in java

Tags: android, kotlin, decimal, decimalformat

i try to only 2 digit after decimal point without last 2 digit roundoff in java.
Here my code :-

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
val gh = df.format(19.14966566)
```

ans of df is = 19.15

but i want only 19.14 as it is last 2 digit of 19.14966566 without roundoff

Comment: Hope  this one will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486878/how-to-cut-off-decimal-in-java-without-rounding

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
double x = 19.14966566;
double y = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100;
O/P-> 19.14
```

In your code style

```
val df = 19.14966566
val gh = Math.floor(x * 100) / 100
gh-> 19.14
```

You can refer this link also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32303271/6838146

Let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...It works for me...

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR
val gh = df.format(19.14966566)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution for you with `NumberFormat`. 
With `NumberFormat` you can explicitly set:

- The Locale
- The minimum number of fraction digits
- The maximum number of fraction digits
- The rounding mode

Like this:

```
val nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)

nf.minimumFractionDigits = 2
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
nf.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN

val gh = nf.format(19.14966566)
println(gh)
```

will print:

```
19.14
```